# Can I create PayPal shopping cart for different vendor

Tags: php, paypal

I have items and vendors table each vendors have different items to sell and all the vendors have their own email and password for login. I want to create shopping cart with PayPal when the user want to buy something they will click buy and it will add it to paypal shopping cart and then when they process to payment the money will go to the vendor. I'm not really sure how to start or is this good idea or not any suggestion?

Comment: There are a number of ways to handle that depending on your overall goal.  Are you wanting to take a commission on the sale for yourself, or should the entire amount go to the vendor?

Comment: the amount will go all to the vendor

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info provided I would recommend using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).  Specifically, you'll be using:

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

In the SEC and DECP request you'll use the PAYMENTINFO_n_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter to specify the account the money should go to.

Using this method you will use your own API credentials in the API calls, and you will not need to worry about setting up permissions or anything for the vendors.

Since you're working with PHP I'd recommend using this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It will make the API calls very quick and easy for you.